# Azure Databricks, could not initialize class org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsConf

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm pretty new to Scala and I'm trying to create a notebook to elaborate data written in an Azure Event Hub. This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._

val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder("MY-CONNECTION-STRING")
  .setEventHubName("EVENT-HUB-NAME")
  .build

val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
  .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)
  
val eventhubs = spark.readStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .options(eventHubsConf.toMap)
  .load()
```

And I get the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsConf$`

Cluster Configuration:

- Databricks Runtime Version: 7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)
- Driver & Worker Type: 14.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU
  Standard_DS3_v2

I have installed the following library:

`com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.17` 
[cluster libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKqc6.png) 
The other JAR installed is to resolve a problem with Logging

The code crashes as soon as I try to create eventHubsConf.

Complete traceback:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsConf$
at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:7)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:70)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:72)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:74)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:76)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:78)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:80)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:82)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:84)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$$iw.<init>(command-2632683088190841:86)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read.<init>(command-2632683088190841:88)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$.<init>(command-2632683088190841:92)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$read$.<clinit>(command-2632683088190841)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line14a6ae940dd14957b7172a4cf8f6cdd348.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at es Scala 2.12 but yoscala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$10(DriverLocal.scala:396)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:645)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:486)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:598)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you restart your cluster?

Comment: Could you please share the details about the cluster runtime versions?

Comment: @SCouto I already restarted the cluster a couple of times but the problem persists

Comment: Thanks @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT I updated the question including SW and HW configuration

Comment: Your runtime includes Scala 2.12 but your package is from scala 2.11. That may be wrong. Try installing this com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17

Comment: Thanks a lot @SCouto that fixed the issue!

Comment: Glad to help, i'll post it as an answer so other people can find it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that your Runtime includes Scala 2.12 but your package is from scala 2.11

Try installing this one

```
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17
```

Comment: What is this second version? How to obtain it?

Comment: You can check how to download the version you need here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs-spark